# Element h7 not allowed as child of element li in this context

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have lot of issue with the HTML5 code, i am new to HTML5. W3c validator shoes many errors can be seen here , anybody can help ?

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcrimsoninformatics.info%2Fdirectus%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an `<h#>` tag inside an `<li>` element should be fine.  However, there is no `<h7>` element defined in HTML5 - only `<h1>` to `<h6>`.